# Can't update my system

Tags: apt, upgrade

Since I installed Pop!_OS, the global performance of my laptop went down and everytime there are different issues,I installed a KDE-neon desktop (having in this way two different desktops Gnome + KDE plasma).

I got the following error message running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu groovy Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho                
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu groovy Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios
```

Comment: Are you running Pop!_OS 20.10?

Comment: yes, that distro is what im using

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at [ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/),
you can see there exist no packages for "groovy" (Ubuntu 20.10, the version your POP!_OS is based on), thus the update fails.

Remove the PPA from your sources, it's likely defined in a file named like `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-*.list`, thus

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-*.list
```

should do the trick (or delete the corresponding line if the PPA is defined in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`) and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

again.

Comment: thanks this worked for me :)